# How to compute $(a+1)^b\pmod{n}$ using $a^b\pmod{n}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

As we know, we can compute $a^b \pmod{n}$ efficiently using Right-to-left binary method [Modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). 
Assume b is a prime number .
Can we compute directly $(a+1)^b\pmod{n}$ using $a^b\pmod{n}$?

Comment: For $b=2$ and $n=3$, $a^b=1\pmod{n}$ for $a\in\{1,2\}$ and yet for those same $a$, $(a+1)^b$ can be either $1$ or $0$ mod $n$. So knowing $a^b$ mod $n$ is not enough to pin down $(a+1)^b$ mod $n$.

Answer (score 1):

In general no, but yes in some special cases, e.g.  if $\ n\mid \pm a^k\! +\! a\! +\! 1\,$ for small $\,k\,$ then

${\rm mod}\ n\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{a\!+\!1\,\equiv\, \pm a^k}\,\Rightarrow\, (\color{#c00}{a\!+\!1})^b \equiv (\color{#c00}{\pm a^k})^b\equiv (\pm1)^b (a^b)^k$

so you need only raise the known result $\,a^b\,$ to a small power $\,k\,$ to get the result.